# posix threads program explanation?

Tags: c, multithreading, pointers, pthreads, posix

I have to learn POSIX threads, still getting my head around pointers and de-referencing, I think I understand the basics of & * and changing values/memory locations. Now we have to start coding POSIX threads, we were given this sample question in our lectures and I can't quite get what's going on.

apparently there is a problem with this code that probably has something to do with parsing arguments, could anyone possibly give me a quick explanation? I have commented what I think is going on

```
typedef struct { int a, b; } pair_t;           /*creating new struct pair_t, takes in 2 integers */

void * add(void *p_in)                         /* here is where I start to get confused, what is the * before add, what kind of parameter is (void *p_in)? */
{
    pair_t *p = (pair_t *)p_in;                /* "*p" is a pointer for a "pair_t", (pair_t *)p_in ? */
    printf("Answer is: %d\n", p->a + p->b);    /* prints out pair_t -> a? */
    return (0);                                /* its a void method so no return value */
}

void adder(int x, int y){                      /* takes two integers as parameters */`
    pthread_t t;                               /* initialises POSIX thread "t" */
    pair_t p;                                  /* initialises new pair_t "p" */
    p.a = x;                                   /* sets p.a and p.b as x and y respectively */
    p.b = y;
    pthread_create(&t, NULL, add, (void *)&p); /* creates a new thread, thread ID is pthread "t", NULL -> default thread attributes, void add = start routine, (void *)&p = thread arguments */
}
```

when the pthread_create is called, are the thread arguments being passed to the add method? and what if anything is wrong with this code?

Comment: You haven't explained how its behavior is different from what you wanted/expected.

Comment: Ahem..... 'pthread_create(&t, NULL, add, (void *)&p);' by the time that add() function is run by your new thread, it's quite likely that  adder() has returned, p has disappeared and add() tries to dereference an illegal pointer - UB.

Comment: Also, you're leaking a `pthread_t`, which means the spawned thread turns into a zombie when it exits.

Comment: do you mean that I just forgot to terminate the thread?

Comment: By default, a thread is created in `joinable` state. It means that after the thread exits, another thread can `pthread_join()` with the thread, synchronizing further execution and optionally using the return value of the joined pthread. `man pthread_create: [...]Only when a  terminated joinable thread  has  been joined are the last of its resources released back to the system.[...]`. Alternatively, you can `pthread_detach()` the thread.

Comment: Please do not use the suffix `_t` for your own type. It is reserved by POSIX for system types.

Answer (score 3):

`void * add(void *p_in)` is a function taking a void pointer as argument and returns a void pointer. Some people find this coding style more readable: `void* add (void* p_in)` (equivalent meaning).

`void*` has the advantage of being a generic pointer which can point at any type. And any pointer type can be converted to/from a void pointer type without explicit casts. So a function that both returns void* and takes void* as parameter is the most generic function you can have.

(The cast `(void *)&p` is fishy: it is superfluous and may indicate that you are doing something wrong, such as compiling C code on a C++ compiler.)

POSIX threads demand that you pass a function pointer to a function with such a format when you create the thread. This will be the thread *callback* function. It must have that exact format or your program will crash and burn.

If you need to pass several parameters, you'll have to bake them together in a struct as in your example, then cast them back to the struct type from inside the callback function.

Regarding the parameters of the phread_create, the manual can tell you as much as I. Basically it goes like this:

```
pthread_create(&t,   // thread to create
               NULL, // attributes, advanced feature, ignore for now
               add,  // thread callback function
               &p);  // pointer to the parameter to pass to the thread callback
```

The return 0 is a sloppy way of writing return NULL. This is bad practice in C, it is preferred to always use the NULL macro.

Comment: @MarkSmith Oh my, indeed that's a rather fatal bug. Can't believe I didn't think of that :) I'll leave this answer as it is and upvote yours.

Comment: @BlueMoon Because it is not self-documenting code. It is not clear if the programmer meant 0 to be NULL, or if they for some reason intended to return a value or an error code. Same reason why for example `if(ptr == NULL)` is so much better and clearer style than `if(!ptr)`.

Comment: @BlueMoon Well, your style is banned by widely-recognized coding standards such as MISRA-C. And since MISRA-C is not a style guide, they have a safety-related rationale for banning that style: treating if statement conditions etc as something that must have essentially bool type leads to stronger typing, and stronger typing leads to less bugs.

Comment: @BlueMoon I'm curious to know then, for what purpose do you think the macro NULL exists?

Comment: @BlueMoon As for the C standard, it allows all kinds of madness. It is not in the slightest concerned about rationales, consistency, readability or program safety. The C standard doesn't care about if your programs work as intended or crash. This is why professional programmers use coding standards to create safer subsets of the dangerous and complicated C language. For POSIX/desktop programming, [CERT C](https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/c/SEI+CERT+C+Coding+Standard) is perhaps more suitable than MISRA-C. It even has a chapter addressing POSIX-specifics.

Comment: @BlueMoon I already mentioned the rationale in the very first comment: explicit code is self-documenting code.

Answer (score 2):

The * before `add` indicates that `add` returns a `void*` - that is, a pointer.  The reason it has to return a `void*` and not some other type, or void, is that that's what functions called with `pthread_create` have to return.

The function `add` is *not* void, contrary to your comment.  It returns a value which is a `void *`.  I'd recommend a quick Google of `void *` pointers.

You can (and should) look up the parameters to `pthread_create` and that would answer your question about its parameters.  The last parameter is passed as the argument to `add`.

Telling you the answer to your assignment is probably not the best way to help you learn... but here it is.  Think about *scope* and try to work it out for yourself before you read my answer.

> I can see one bug - `adder`'s variable `p` has scope local to `adder`.  You pass a pointer to it to `add`.  As soon as `adder` returns, `p` will go out of scope and `add` will be working on memory which may not contain what you want it to.

There may be others that I haven't spotted.

Comment: thanks for the info, this isn't really an assignment, just lecture notes I don't quite understand yet, but I think I'm getting there, yes I looked up void pointers and they seem to be very similar to type parameters from java, nobody ever really explains this stuff well in college, thanks again, I thought that the parameters would be passed to the start routine and you confirmed my suspicions

Answer (score 2):

> what kind of parameter is (void *p_in)?

That's a [void pointer](http://www.c4learn.com/c-programming/c-void-pointers/), basically a pointer that doesn't have a type associated with it. POSIX threads only accept void pointers as arguments, and to use them you have to [cast](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_type_casting.htm) them to the type you want, which is what's done on the first line of add().
The code fails because p is a local variable and is discarded once adder returns (and since add() is a thread, adder() doesn't wait for it to return), to fix it either make p a global variable, or make adder() wait until the add() thread returns.
edit: as Martin James pointed out, dynamically allocating the p with malloc, passing the resulting pointer to the thread and calling free on it at the end of the thread would also do the trick.

Comment: Yes, I missed you answer and wrote my own:(

Comment: OTOH, you missed the classic 'allocate the struct with new/malloc and delete/free it at the end of the thread function'.  No need for globals or waiting.

Answer (score 0):

Do not allocate thread argument struts/objects/whatever in automatic storage in the function block that creates the thread unless the lifetime of the creating function/block is guaranteed to be the same as, or longer, than the time that the created thread requires access to it.

Comment: Note: @wrinkl3 had seen this 40 minutes ago, but I missed it - upvote him/her, not me:(